# Get token for Microsoft Graph API in Java

Tags: java, oauth, microsoft-graph-api, token, azure-ad-msal

I would like to use Microsoft Graph API to manage Drive files, but I have some trouble with authentication...

I have the code below to get the rights to access to my account :

```
try(InputStream propFile = MicrosoftEngine.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("microsoft.properties")){
      Properties prop = new Properties();
      prop.load(propFile);

      setGraphClient(GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(request -> {
        // Add the access token in the Authorization header
        request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + prop.getProperty("token"));
      }).buildClient());

      IDriveItemCollectionPage children = graphClient.me().drive().root().children().buildRequest().get();
      setDrive(children);
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But for the moment, the value of the "token" property is taken from Microsoft Graph Explorer :

[Example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWVmR.png)

After a while (an hour maybe), the token expires and I need to send another request via the Graph Explorer to have a new token and copy/paste it into my Java code.

But this is not convenient... How can I get this token value in Java ? Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: You might need to make a separate request to request a token. What does the API documentation say about this?

Comment: For Authentication first you need to implement MSAL to get the token from AAD. You can start from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts) to implement authentication in Microsoft Graph. You can try [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/java) to get started with implementation of Microsoft Graph for JAVA.

Comment: @MLarionov actually this is a code I got from the documentation...

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity Thank you, I've tested the sample and I got some results with Calendar data, I'm going to try to acces to my OneDrive files with the authentication part of the sample :)

Comment: Glad that it helped you. Moving this to Answer. please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work :)-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Authentication first you need to implement MSAL to get the token from AAD. You can start from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts) to implement authentication in Microsoft Graph. You can try [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/java) to get started with implementation of Microsoft Graph for JAVA.

Comment: Hello again @Shiva-MSFTIdentity, in the sample a DeviceCode is used to acquire the token, and I tried to replace it with IntegratedWindowsAuthenticationParameters, to avoid user sign-in (I use my personnal account). But I got an error : "com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalServiceException: WsTrust endpoint not found in metadata document"... Is there something I should modify in my App Registration ?

Comment: Hi @digimip09, You can follow this [public document](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Integrated-Windows-Authentication) implementing Integrated Windows Authentication. If you have any more issues with Authentication mainly, please create a stack overflow question with tag azure-active-directory so that the Identity team can look into it.